# Why my submit button change his colour when its disabled because I selected other radio button in Angular 9

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

The problem I have right now is that I have my login and has two radio buttons one is selected for default until now its all fine, the submit button looks disabled but in the moment i click the other radio button the colour of the submit button change to the colour that it should have when is available.

---

Even when the colour of the button change you cant send the information until you put the correct data.

How can I solve this problem? . I'm using `angular material`, `ng-bootstrap` and `scss`.

- Below I will let my code and pictures of it looks like

Code of the html where the `radio buttons` are located and the first form for the login page.

```html
<div class="bg"> 
<div class="main-div color">
    <mat-card class="z-depth center" flex="50" >
        <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" [(ngModel)]="radio_btn">
            <mat-radio-button  [value]="true" >User</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button [value]="false">Admin</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group> 
            <div class="row justify-content-center" *ngIf="radio_btn==false;else form2">
                <form class="example-form " [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="sendUser()">
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                        <input matInput formControlName="Identifier" placeholder="Identifier" >
                    </mat-form-field><br>
                    <div *ngIf="loginForm.get('Identifier').hasError('Identifier') && loginForm.get('Identifier').touched">Introduce an email</div><br>
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                        <input matInput formControlName="Password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                    </mat-form-field><br>
                    <div *ngIf="loginForm.get('Password').hasError('Password') && loginForm.get('Password').touched">Introduce the correctly password</div><br>
                    <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" class="colour_button" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <ng-template #form2> 
                <app-home-admin></app-home-admin>
            </ng-template>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the `<app-home-admin></app-home-admin>` is the other form that has the same code of the form above but without the radio buttons.

`SCSS file`

```css
example-icon {
    padding: 0 14px;
  }

  .example-spacer {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }
  button {
    display: block;            
    width: 100%;
    margin: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    color: $orange !important;
  }

  .colour_button{
    background: $colour_button;
  }
```

And this is how i change the colour of the submit button when is disabled, its located in the `style.scss`.

```css
.md-button.md-raised.md-primary.formPage:not(.disabledclassname) {
    position: right !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color:#008cba !important;  
    }
```

`FormGroup` in the ts file

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  radio_btn:boolean = true;
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  bSignIn = false;
  isSigned:boolean = false;
  snackMessage:string = 'Introduce valid data';
  public errorMessage: string;

  constructor(
    private _builder:FormBuilder, private usersService: UsersService,private router: Router,
    public _snackBar: MatSnackBar
    ) {}

  sendUser(){
    this.bSignIn = true;

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Identifier', this.loginForm.get('Identifier').value);
    formData.append('Password', this.loginForm.get('Password').value);
    this.usersService.validateUserCredentials(formData)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.bSignIn = false;
        let auxRes: any = res;
        if(auxRes.type == 'success'){
          let auxUser = { 
            personId: auxRes.person_id,
            clientId: auxRes.client_id,
            projectId: auxRes.project_id
          }
          this.isSigned = true;
          localStorage.setItem('leadLogged', JSON.stringify(auxUser));
          this.goToUsersDashboard(auxRes.id);
        }
        else
          this.openSnackBar(this.snackMessage);
      },
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ValidateForms();
  }

  ValidateForms(){
    this.loginForm = this._builder.group({
      Identifier: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(7)])],
      Password: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(5)])]
    })
  }
}
```

This is how it looks like, it should always look disabled until you put the correct information.

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you add your formGroup as well? from ts file

Comment: Yes let me put it on the question @RobertB.

Comment: Its already updated @RobertB.

Comment: Couple updates you could do: 1. check for pristine as well: <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="loginForm.pristine || loginForm.invalid " class="colour_button" type="submit">Sign in</button> 2. Add a required to your form input fields. One of these or both should work. Also adding your code on something like stackblitz.com can help others easily troubleshoot.

Comment: That didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This is how i solve it***

Putting this in the button

```html
<button mat-raised-button [class.black]="!loginForm.invalid" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

and adding this class to the scss file

```css
.black {
  background-color:$black !important;  ;
 }
```