# SnackBar doesnt show up in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have one `SnackBar` that should be displayed in a login when you put the incorrect information, but when that happen the `SnackBar` doesnt show up its overlap by other element, how can i fix it?

Here below i will put how I'm trying to do it

`sendAdmin()` is the function that is called by a button in the page

```js
snackMessage:string = 'Introduce valid data';

  constructor(private _builder:FormBuilder,private router: Router,
    private adminService: AdminService,public _snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

    openSnackBar(message: string){
      this._snackBar.open(message, 'X', {
        duration: 3000,
      });
    }
  sendAdmin(){
    this.bSignIn = true;
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('email', this.loginForm.get('email').value);
    formData.append('password', this.loginForm.get('password').value);

    this.adminService.validateAdminCredentials(formData)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.bSignIn = false;
        let auxRes: any = res;

        if(auxRes.type == 'success'){
          let auxUser = {
            personId: auxRes.id,
            clientId: auxRes.client_id,
            firstName: auxRes.first_name
          }
          this.isSigned = true;
          localStorage.setItem('leadLoggedAdmin', JSON.stringify(auxUser));
          this.goToAdminDashboard(auxRes.first_name);
        }  
      },
      err => {
        this.bSignIn = false;
        this.openSnackBar(this.snackMessage);
        //window.alert('Introduce valid data');
      }
    );
  }
```

Also I'm importing `import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';`

This is how it looks like right now, overlap

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it putting to the bottom bar a class, like this:

```css
.behind{
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to import `MatSnackBarModule` in your module where the component declared.
If you did it, please make sure that you import material theme style in your `styles.scss` or in `styles` section in `angular.json`.

If an element overlapped, please try this:

```
this._snackBar.open(message, 'X', {
   duration: 3000,
   panelClass: 'snack-bar'
});
```

And set `z-index: 99` on the `snack-bar` class. You need to define this class in `styles.scss`

Comment: weird then, it actually should work. maybe there is a class or an element overlapped?
you can inspect the DOM changes?

Comment: Yes that is what it happens still don't know how to put the snackBar in front the element

Comment: Yes that didn't work, see the picture i post to see how is displayed, the `snackBar` is the blue one

Comment: haha so snackbar actually works, you can set z-index on the overlapped element as well? like z-index: 10

Comment: See how I solve it, you gave the key, i didn't put it to the overlapped element i put it to the bottom bar

Comment: the yellow bar you mean?

Comment: Yes, the orange

Comment: Please if you can, see my another question about the colour of the submit button when is disabled

Comment: give me link to the question

Comment: This is the link `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60437332/why-my-submit-button-change-his-colour-when-its-disabled-because-i-selected-othe` and thanks

Answer (score 0):

How is this component rendered? Is it possible that this component is being re-rendered due to a ng-if or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your module `MatSnackBarModule` in `app.module` file and remove its import from the shared module.

EDIT: Did you check your console? Is there any exception thrown?

**Updated Answer**

I think you should need to set positioning of snack bar using `verticalPosition` as `top`

See the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api)